# Python Recursion Issue; I Can’t Change My Hard Code Into a Recursive Function

Tags: python, recursion

```
beside(picture,picture)         #beside takes two pictures as arguments and prints them side by side in a 1:1 ratio.

stackn(n,picture)         #stackn takes a number and a picture as arguments and prints n number of shapes in a vertical row.

show(picture)        #show takes a picture as an argument and shows it on the canvas
```

In this case picture is the parameter `heart_bb`:

```
(n=2)#      show(beside((stackn(1,heart_bb)),(stackn(2,heart_bb))))

(n=3)#      show(beside((stackn(1,heart_bb)),(beside((stackn(2,heart_bb)),(stackn(4,heart_bb))))))

(n=4)#    show(beside((stackn(1,heart_bb)),(beside((stackn(2,heart_bb)),(beside((stackn(4,heart_bb)),(stackn(8,heart_bb))))))))
```

**My task is to come up with a recursive function(I’m going to call it test):**

```
def test(n, picture):
```

I need this function to return the corresponding line of code shown above. For example, `test(3,heart_bb)` should return the line of code for `n=3`. Likewise, `test(4,heart_bb)` will return the line of code for `n=4`.

It has to work for any `n>1`, but after `n=5` coding it gets really tedious.

```
def fractal(picture,n):
   if n==1:
       return(picture)

   else:
       return(beside((fractal(picture,(n-1))),(stackn((2**(n-1)),  (picture)))))
```

Comment: Please format your answer. It's pretty hard to read.

Comment: [How to format your code.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mainly need an idea of how you can do it and not a way to find someone that writes the code for you.
I would suggest to use a n-ary `beside` operation in place of your one, in such a way to simplify the code for n=2,3,4,... Since I cannot modify it I will define a new one in terms of your binary operation in this way:

```
def beside_pictures(pictures):
    assert len(pictures) > 0
    result = pictures[-1]
    for tmp in pictures[:-1:-1]:  # reverse order, starting from -1
        result = beside(tmp, result)
    return result
```

Now we are ready to transform your test function in a one line function:

```
def test(n, picture):
    assert n > 0
    show(beside_pictures([stackn(2**i,picture) for i in range(n)]))
```

---

UPDATE: If the requirement to have a recursive function is strict, one possible solution is the following one:

```
def test(n, picture):
    if n == 1:
        return stackn(1,picture)
    return beside(test(n-1, picture), stackn(2**(n-1),picture))
```