# python recursion how to turn hard code into recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

```
beside(picture,picture) # stacks 2 pictures beside each other, with the first one on the left, and the second one on the right.

stackn(n,picture) # stacks n number of pictures on top of each other in a vertical line

show(picture) # prints the whole picture on the canvas
```

The aim of my assignment is to create a function that takes the 2 parameters n and picture and prints it onto a canvas in a pattern as shown below.

```
test(n,picture)
```

[image]

( this is for n=4 )

this is what I have came up with so far.

```
def fractal(picture,n):
   if n==1:
       return(picture)

   else:
       return(beside((fractal(picture,(n-1))),(stackn((2**(n-1)),  (picture)))))
```

But this code produces this instead.

[image]

the following lines of code are the hard code versions of the solution.

```
(n=2)#      show(beside((stackn(1,heart_bb)),(stackn(2,heart_bb))))

(n=3)#      show(beside((stackn(1,heart_bb)),(beside((stackn(2,heart_bb)),(stackn(4,heart_bb))))))

(n=4)#    show(beside((stackn(1,heart_bb)),(beside((stackn(2,heart_bb)),(beside((stackn(4,heart_bb)),(stackn(8,heart_bb))))))))
```

Im a beginner at python, so i really appreciate any help i can get!

Comment: [Hint.](https://imgur.com/a/NBCrV)

Comment: Well, you didn't really come up with it since you left [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510148/python-recursion-issue-i-can-t-change-my-hard-code-into-a-recursive-function) open an hour ago. You haven't accepted the answer there or commented on it, so it's unclear where your issue lies overall.

Comment: @roganjosh: The code here doesn't seem to originate from the answer there; the questioner edited it into the question there, and then the answerer edited a similar but distinct function into their answer later.

Comment: It looks like the general structure of the recursion is correct, you just need to adjust the sizes appropriately.

Comment: @user2357112 unless I'm missing something, the function at the bottom of that question is identical to the only actual code block in this question

Comment: @roganjosh: How is that supposed to mean they didn't come up with it?

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the hint dude managed to get it right already! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
def fractal(picture,n):
   if n == 1:
       return(picture)
   else:
       return(beside(picture, stack(2, fractal(picture,(n-1)))))
```

The meaning of the code is, if n is 1 return the picture it self.
Otherwise, put two smaller pictures one on top of the other and put them beside one picture and go on and on.

You can create some help functions to make your code more clear such as

```
def stacktwo(picture):
    return stack(2, picture)

def fractal(picture,n):
   if n == 1:
       return(picture)
   else:
       smaller = fractal(picture, (n-1))
       return(beside(picture, stacktwo(smaller)))
```